# Как лучше сделать progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Пример]

Как лучше сделать такие  прогрессбары, нужно чтобы ползунки подстраивались под значения, указанные ранее

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Написано же прогресс бар. Поэтому имеем следующее:

```js
let progress = document.querySelectorAll('[data-progress]');

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 progress.forEach(element => {
 
  let progress_width = +(element.getAttribute('data-progress')); 
 
  //Если наши скиллы выше 100%, немного становимся скромнее.
 if(progress_width > 100) {
  progress_width = 100;
 }
  element.style.width = progress_width + '%';
 })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.wrapper .rating-title {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.wrapper .rating-item {
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #42bcff;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.wrapper .rating-item_progress {
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #42bcff;
  -webkit-transition: cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1) 1s;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1) 1s;
}
.wrapper .rating-item_progress:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #42bcff;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translatey(-50%);
          transform: translatey(-50%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> 
 <div class="rating">
  <div class="rating-title">
   HTML
  </div>
  <div class="rating-item">
   <div class="rating-item_progress" data-progress="30">
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rating-title">
   CSS
  </div>
  <div class="rating-item">
   <div class="rating-item_progress" data-progress="130">
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rating-title">
   Javascript
  </div>
  <div class="rating-item">
   <div class="rating-item_progress" data-progress="70">
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для этой цели теги `<meter>` или `<progress>`; а чтобы дать возможность пользователю менять значение, используйте тег `<input>`.

```html
<meter value=0.42></meter>
<progress value=0.13></progress>
<input type=range value=50>
```

Comment: Не встечал ни meter ни progress, а какие браузеры их поддерживают? И что увидят владельцы мобилок?

Comment: все современные браузеры поддерживают

Comment: Не согласен (браузеров развелось много), лучше хотя бы добавить что html5-совместимые. Или так  https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_progress.asp хотя бы.